# Vue em conflito com Bootstrap?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Estou implementado Vuejs em um Laravel5.7 meu e percebi que esta ocorrendo aparentemente um conflito com quase todas minhas nav-tabs, pois quando vou trocando de aba nas nav-tabs, independente de quantas abas haja, ele não vai tirando a classe "show" das abas que vou saindo, tira apenas a "active", assim as minhas abas ficam com o conteudo todo junto conforme vou passando.
Eu estou usando atualmente funções com jquery para remover manualmente a classe "show" conforme vou passando, mas acho que não é legal eu ir fazendo isso por todo meu projeto.
Alguem ja passou por isso e sabe como resolver?

OBS: Antes de eu começar a implementar o Vue isso não ocorria, funcionava normalmente a troca de abas.
OBS²: Percebi agora que não sei porque, mesmo utilizando a mesma versão do bootstrap, no projeto sem o Vue, não é adicionada a classe "show" na aba ativa, mas no projeto com o Vue é, e é necessario uma função manual para retira-la.

Comment: Cara se vc estiver indexando o CDN do jQuery direto do link oferecido pelo Bootstrap pode ser que de pau mesmo... Pelo menos eu reparei a poucos dias que agora eles indicam a versão **Slim** por lá `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"` isso buga alguma coisas. Confere ai se é essa versão que está no seu projeto. Se for tente substituir por `src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"` para ver se resolve. É só um teste não tenho certeza se vai resolver ai...

Comment: Ola, não estou usando CDN, uso os arquivos baixados e peguei diretamente do site do jquery, e o estranho é que meus dois projetos estão usando as mesmas versões de BOOTSTRAP e JQUERY e mesmo assim o com Vue adiciona a classe "show" e o SEM Vue não adiciona e portanto não é necessario funções para retirar manualmente

Comment: Cara é "muito" contra indicado utilizar **jQuery** com **Vue, Angular, React, etc..**. Pq não utiliza o Bootstrap próprio para Vue?

Comment: Achei ele meio complicado de mexer e instalar e eu teria que refazer a estilização do site todo usando o bootstrap próprio do Vue?